# How to get the Xpath of the drop down menu without hardcoding

Tags: java, selenium, automation, cucumber

I am trying to get the Xpath of the drop down menu as iam doing a menu comparison.

But getting a error:

[object Text]. It should be an element.

Below is my Xpath:

WebElement submenuitem = menuLink.findElement(By.xpath("//button//text()"));

Had Also tried with the below Xpath:

List list = menuLink.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'mat-list-item-content')]"));

```
                String element = list.get(0).getAttribute("innerText");
```

but this fetches only the first text from the drop down ..
Dropdown menu has :

Vessel Database
Partner Database
User Management
Export to Excel

So i need to read these dropdown menus ... Iam doing a menu bar comparison so cannot hard cord the text ...Any Leads will be helpful

HTML:

expand_more**Vessel Database****Partner Database****User Management****Export Excel**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: html is added fully  but not able to format it to show the full code